# high number of lwps in solaris 11 associated to weblogic instances

Tags: java, weblogic11g

I have a weblogic 11g cluster, with 2 physical servers. The instances are balanced with F5, but on server 2, the six weblogic instances have a high number of lwps, more than 20000.
A thread dump of a weblogic instance was exported, and many occurrences of a log4j class can be seen.
I need to correct this problem, because server 2 reaches 100,000 and the machine crashes.
Thanks, I look forward to your suggestions.

1. Server 2 (number lwps)

```
[user@serverwls2 ~]$ prstat -a 1 1 | egrep "java|Total"
 25685 soracle   6040936K 5590440K sleep    59    0  10:43:47 1.279% java/6404
 29776 soracle   6033888K 5656640K sleep    59    0  10:43:17 1.019% java/6603
  8190 soracle   5501688K 3571712K sleep    59    0   0:41:39 0.058% java/4029
  8633 soracle   5650160K 4005776K sleep    59    0   1:18:00 0.046% java/5186
  8635 soracle   5630848K 4220944K sleep    59    0   1:17:02 0.043% java/4963
  8634 soracle   5643592K 4078840K sleep    59    0   1:14:07 0.043% java/5160
Total: 96 processes, 33568 lwps, load averages: 1.64, 1.61, 1.63
```

2. Extract thread dump (pid 29776) export with jstack

```
    2022-05-17 16:53:00
    Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.331-b06 mixed mode):
    "Attach Listener" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000115d3b800 nid=0x3443 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
       Locked ownable synchronizers:
            - None
    "Thread-13074" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000115d39800 nid=0x3442 waiting on condition [0xfffffffc09cff000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
            at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:104)
       Locked ownable synchronizers:
            - None
    "Thread-13072" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000116e36000 nid=0x3440 waiting on condition [0xfffffffc09eff000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
            at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:104)
       Locked ownable synchronizers:
            - None
```

3. Occurrence number in thread dump

```
    [user@serverwls2 ~]$ grep "org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run" pid29776_dump.txt | wc -l
        6450
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable `configureAndWatch` as a workaround to your `FileWatchdog` *issue*.

Also, review the `log4j.xml` for permissions, it looks like cannot be read.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I'm going to check the option to disable "configureandWatch".
Regarding the permissions in log4j.xml, they are the same on both servers, this problem only occurs on server 2.
We currently use log4j-1.2.15.jar on both servers.